# How do I set the computer to suspend when battery is critically low?

Tags: power-management, suspend

I accidentally clicked on the option "When power is critically low" under System Settings>Power. The original entry was blank, but the only two options after I clicked were Hibernate and Shutdown. I want to set it back to Suspend.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no option to suspend available.

You cannot suspend when the power is critically low, to suspend you need power to save the session to RAM allowing you to resume quicker, if you loose power you loose the current suspend state.

Hibernate copies the current state to the hard drive, it is slower but you can turn off the power.

Shutdown is obvious - you will lose any data in the active session and have a new session on restart.

Comment: In an ideal world, maybe. I would LOVE it if I could configure my machine to suspend when it falls below e.g. 15% of the battery (easily enough for several hours in suspend) because as it is, I can only configure it to shutdown (which kind of guarantees you lose data) or hibernate (which is completely broken on my machine). So here's to unnecessary constraints...

Comment: I am facing the same problem. It used to suspend when battery is critically low. But as in the question, I accidentally clicked on the option "When power is critically low" under System Settings>Power. The original entry was blank but now I can only select 'Power Off'. Hence, my computer shutdowns when battery is critically low. I would like to make it suspend in that case. Don't know how to get back to the original state where it used to suspend.

Comment: In Ubuntu 12.04, the "hibernate" option is disabled, and the computer restarts instead of suspending when the battery is critically low.

Comment: @chapagain I am facing exactly the same problem. Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @AndersonGreen I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @Mark Rooney Is it possible to add the "suspend" option? I tried enabling "hibernate" once, and after that, I began to encounter numerous stability issues.

Comment: as the dconf settings mentioned in other answer show, it is not true that "there is no option to suspend". But according to comments under [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/92818/47206) answer, the solution works in some system versions (14.04) or in some laptops but not in others.

Comment: Although the answer is correct (regarding the configuration of *UPower*), it is still possible if you reconfigure *systemd* (`man systemd-sleep.conf`) to actually suspend for e.g. *UPower's* `HybridSleep` action.

Comment: Yeah, it is 2022 and it still a luxury if Linux manages to hibernate properly (or come back from hibernation). Especially us with a graphics card. In this case, suspend is better than nothing.

Answer (score 23):

To change this setting back to suspend, use dconf-editor. Go to org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power and change critical-battery-action to suspend.

Alternatively, in a terminal session use the command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power critical-battery-action 'suspend'
```

The `gsettings` command is resident by default while `dconf-editor` requires installing via:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Comment: Is there any bug on Launchpad for this behavior of blank being suspend?

Comment: No longer works as of [GNOME 3.28.2](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/8liuyb/where_did_the_critical_battery_action_go_in_gnome/). Does anyone have an alternative solution?

Comment: gsettings list-recursively | grep percentage   ;   gsettings list-recursively | grep critical

Answer (score 10):

I don't have sufficient rep to edit or comment, so if anyone would care to, this is a comment/edit for AtomHeartFather's answer.

You may also change the values for what percent is considered low/critical battery using dconf-tools. In the same power section, modify the following values to the desired percentages.

`percentage-action`

`percentage-critical`

`percentage-low`

Note: Special consideration goes to the `percentage-action` setting which will trigger the `critical-battery-action` setting.

Comment: to change percentages, according to [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/92818/47206) answer, the `use-time-for-policy` entry has also to be changed  (un-checked, or set to 'false'): `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power use-time-for-policy false`. But this does **not** seem to work for sure on all systems/machines.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a simple bash script which will do it on any linux... just add this script to startup... every two minutes the script checks for battery status and suspend if battery lower that 11%....

```
#!/bin/sh
flag=0
while [ 1 ]; do
  var=$(upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0| grep -E "percentage"| grep -o '[0-9]*')
  if [ $var -lt 11 ] && [ $flag -eq 0 ]; then
    systemctl suspend
    flag=1
  elif [ $var -gt 11 ] && [ $flag -eq 1 ]; then
    flag=0
  fi
  sleep 120
done
```

Comment: Love, simple and works fine in 18.04. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem.

I was extremely frustrated whenever my computer would blackout, while i was doing serious work.

I wrote a script to check the A/C Power sate every two minutes and hibernate when the power goes off. Please modify according to your battery's health. My battery could pnly work for two minutes after mains power outage.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $(cat /sys/class/power_supply/AC0/online) == *0* ]] ; then

    echo 'On battery power'
    #pmi action suspend

    dbus-send --system --print-reply \
    --dest="org.freedesktop.UPower" \
    /org/freedesktop/UPower \
    org.freedesktop.UPower.Suspend

#else
#    echo 'On Ac Power'
fi
```

I put the script in a file called `powerMon.sh` and set that up as a `cron job` that runs every two minutes.

Answer (score 1):

On 12.04 I used `sleepd` to suspend the machine when battery was low or the machine was idle.

Although sleepd is not packaged for Ubuntu 14.04, and has even been orphaned by its developer, it is possible to [compile and install it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/421593/put-ubuntu-pc-to-standby-after-x-minutes) yourself.

Installation on Ubuntu 12.04:

```
sudo apt-get install sleepd
```

Edit the file `/etc/default/sleepd` and set the following:

```
# -E       Do not poll events (since they weren't working for me).
# -c 60    Poll every 60 seconds.
# -u 900   Sleep after 15 minutes idle time when on battery,
# -U 3600  or 60 minutes when on AC power,
# -b 3     or when battery power drops below 3%.
# -H       (optional) Use upower instead of ACPI.

PARAMS="-E -c 60 -u 900 -U 3600 -b 3"
```

Then restart the daemon:

```
sudo service sleepd restart
```

It also has options to stay awake if there is network activity, but these stopped working for me.

On my machine, apparently ACPI was not always reporting the temperature correctly, so I needed to add `-H` to tell sleepd to read temperatures from upower instead of ACPI.  I discovered the incorrect readings, after some unexpected syspends, by adding `-v` and watching the logfile with `tail -f /var/log/*log | grep --line-buffered sleepd`.

(I had a weird bug on one laptop with 12.04 that the machine would wake up again immediately after suspending, but only if sleepd was suspending due to low battery, not due to idle time.  I hope you won't have that experience too!  The problem never happened under 14.04.)

Answer (score 0):

On latest version of Ubuntu the batter critical actions aren't available on the UI. However, you can set it up as below.

edit /etc/Upower/Upowerc.conf and set

```
UsePercentageForPolicy=true
PercentageLow=20
PercentageCritical=8
PercentageAction=5
CriticalPowerAction=Hibernate
```

Now, restart the upower systemd unit:

```
systemctl restart upower
```

Comment: wrong filename c

Answer (score -1):

There's a way to disable suspension / power off completely.

`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power critical-battery-action 'false'`

(in case it's showing critically low even at 100%)