# Put ubuntu PC to standby after X minutes

Tags: 13.10, suspend

We've been using `sleepd` with ubuntu 12.04 to put public desktops to suspend after 5-10 minutes of inactivity. We are planning to deploy 13.10 (later move to 14.04), and have found out that `sleepd` package [is missing](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=sleepd&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all).

Is there any other tool or a system wide setting to do this job? How other system administrators solve this problem?

**EDIT:** In our dormitory we have 90+ students. Some have regular user access and some use only the guest account. The solution must work when there aren't any users logged in.

Comment: You can [always install the .deb](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/sleepd_2.04_i386.deb)

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: It won't work because it depends on "libhal >= 0.5.8.1". And hal is removed also.

Comment: What do Xubuntu and Lubuntu use?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test it, I could be missing a step.

1. Use System Setting → Power / Brightness. Set all setting you need and as you want
2. Create an override file from the current user settings and place it in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/`

   ```
   echo "[org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power]" > 90_mypower.gschema.override
   gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power | awk '{ gsub("org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power ","") ; print $1"="$2 }' >> 90_mypower.gschema.override

   sudo mv 90_mypower.gschema.override /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
   sudo chown root:root /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/90_mypower.gschema.override
   sudo chmod +r /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/90_mypower.gschema.override
   ```
3. Compile the schemas

   ```
   sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
   ```
4. Create a lock file for all `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power` keys  and place it in `/etc/dconf/db/gdm.d/locks/`

   ```
   gsettings list-keys org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power | xargs -L 1 -I{} echo /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/{} > 90-mypower-locks

   sudo cp 90-mypower-locks /etc/dconf/db/gdm.d/locks/90-mypower-locks
   sudo chown root:root /etc/dconf/db/gdm.d/locks/90-mypower-locks
   sudo chmod +r /etc/dconf/db/gdm.d/locks/90-mypower-locks
   ```
5. Update for locks

   ```
   sudo dconf update
   ```

---

As you are looking for system administration, nice to learn:

1. Watch `dconf` for change

   ```
   dconf watch /
   ```
2. Change power setting from GUI, watch for messages
3. Open `dconf-editor`, go through same path, select a key
4. Look at bottom, it shows its schema name/id: `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power`

References:

- [dconf System Administrator Guide](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/dconf/SystemAdministrators)
- [Shouldn't dconf-editor and gsettings access the same database?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/416556/shouldnt-dconf-editor-and-gsettings-access-the-same-database)
- [dconf Settings: defaults and locks](http://www.mattfischer.com/blog/?p=431)
- `man gsetting`, `man dconf`

Comment: This is a different approach, and needs a bit more testing than the modified sleepd answer. I'll give this also a try in the weekend. Thank you for the references.

Answer (score 1):

On the bottom of this answer are instructions for installing sleepd if you really insist. However that package is pretty much outdated for modern hardware.

If you are going to write a program, you can consider the following sources:

- Devices in `/dev/input/`
- If a user is logged in, rely on the desktop session manager. Its properties for consideration are described at [How does ubuntu determine inactivity before suspending?](https://askubuntu.com/q/170307/6969)

Instead of using [`sleep(3)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/sleep.3) in the code (like sleepd does), it is more battery-friendly if you use [`poll(3)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/poll.3) or [`select(3)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/select.3) which have a timeout parameter. (This assumes that the `/dev/input/*` devices are poll-able, I don't know if that is the case but you should look up the documentation)

---

Upstream ([git repo](http://git.kitenet.net/?p=sleepd.git)) has already removed the default hal dependency ([commit](http://git.kitenet.net/?p=sleepd.git;a=commitdiff;h=3b8e8a3d2babda82f0a07a38f716c202909d3e86;hp=20d2b6802508289306e609e6223191f726ab21d0)), so you can try building from sources. The following commands were tested in a Kubuntu 13.10 Live environment. It installs the build dependencies, fixes a bug in the Makefile that prevented HAL from getting disabled and finally creates a deb package.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential git debhelper libapm-dev
git clone git://git.kitenet.net/sleepd.git
cd sleepd
sed 's/ifdef USE_HAL/ifeq ($(USE_HAL), 1)/' -i Makefile
dpkg-buildpackage -b -us -uc
```

This produces a `sleepd_2.05_amd64.deb` package in the parent directory which you can then install on machines. This package requires a battery or AC interface to be present (e.g. `/sys/class/power_supply/*`), otherwise it will try APM. Since modern machines do not use APM, but ACPI, it will exit silently.

So while the package builds and install fine, you are better off with writing a new daemon if something like this is not already implemented.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will give it a try in the weekend.

Comment: Sorry for not answering. I tried the git method, and as you have written it won't work when there is nothing in power_supply.

Comment: Thanks for the guide. The repo has since moved [to here](http://git.kitenet.net/?p=zzattic/sleepd.git).  I found I needed to use `-H` (and I also used `-E`) in `/etc/default/sleepd`.  My final config was: `PARAMS="-H -E -c 60 -u 900 -U 3600 -b 3"`

Answer (score 0):

is the power settings under system settings missing because thats where you can graphically set the time

[image]

as you can see if you have this which I'm sure you have, then you can modify it.

Comment: This is only for one user, and when a user is logged in. I need a system wide solution, which cannot be modified by users accidentally. Sorry, I wasn't specific.