# How do I set the computer to turn off screen when battery is critically low?

Tags: battery

I read in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/203788/279148) answer that to set the configuration to suspend we need to type:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power critical-battery-action 'suspend'
```

However I want just to turn off the screen. The reason is that I believe the battery meter is broken, but the battery has power to last about one hour.

Meanwhile I'll simply disable any action when the battery is critically low typing:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power critical-battery-action 'nothing'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just leave the `gsettings` on `nothing` and use the System Settings - Brightness and lock - "dim screen to save power" (use max 80%) and in the same screen "Turn screen off when inactive for 10 minutes".

The other way is to interfere in the suspend script, but if all you want is to turn off the monitor, the above is a much simpler solution.