# Power Suspend inconsistently working

Tags: 14.04, suspend, power-management, shutdown

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 desktop. I rely on the power suspend to suspend my system when I am inactive for longer than 30 minutes.

[image]

For some reason, this doesn't always work.

I came to my system today and saw that it was still running.

How can I ensure that my system correctly powers down from inacitvity?

Essentially, I want my computer to power down/suspend/sleep if:

- I haven't pressed a key on my keyboard in the last 30 minutes
- I haven't moved my mouse in the last 30 minutes.

The in-built Power Saving utility is clearly not working as expected.

Comment: This is probably not a good solution to recommend, but [I use sleepd](http://askubuntu.com/questions/75886/how-do-i-set-the-computer-to-suspend-when-battery-is-critically-low/704698#704698).

Comment: are you sure that nothing at user level was running when you left your pc? because some applications are impeding the system to suspend if they are running.

Comment: @Layke: Are you using any bit-torrent client like **qbittorrent**? Like this there are many applications which **inhibit system sleeps** when they are active.

Comment: This could be it. I dont run bittorrent on my client, but perhaps I have something which as you mention inhibits the shutdown. It's a dev machine, so I have open things like chrome, sublime, skype, shutter, spotify, command terminals, xchat. Maybe I need a different solution for shutting down. My only requirements are, if I dont move my mouse or keyboard within 30 minutes, go into sleep.